# How to get first day data of previous 12 months from every month in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need data from every month only first date data from last 12 months.
i.e. 01-05-2020 to 21-04-2021 (current date), but only data required for first day.
i.e. 01-05-2020, 01-06-2020.....01-05-2021 dates data only

```
const match = {
  $match: {
  date: {
    $gte: 01-05-2020,
    $lte: 21-04-2021,
  },
  userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId),
  amount: { $gt: 0 }
 },
};
```

Any idea will be helpful to me. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: { $eq: [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date"  }, 1 ] }, //match month
      $or: [ // match any one of these
        { $and: [ // match year and month
            { $expr: { $eq: [{ "$year": "$date" }, 2020 ] } },
            { $expr: { $gte: [{ "$month": "$date" }, 5 ] } }
          ] 
        },
        { $and: [ // match year and month
            { $expr: { $eq: [{ "$year": "$date" }, 2021 ] } }, 
            { $expr: { $lte: [{ "$month": "$date" }, 4 ] } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

---

Get current year and month from `$$NOW`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: { $eq: [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$dt" }, 1 ] },
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            { $expr: { $eq: [ { "$year": "$dt" }, { $subtract: [{ "$year": "$$NOW" }, 1 ] } ] } },
            { $expr: { $gt: [ { "$month": "$dt" }, { "$month": "$$NOW" } ] } }
          ]
        },
        {
          $and: [
            { $expr: { $eq: [ { "$year": "$dt" }, { "$year": "$$NOW" } ] } },
            { $expr: { $lte: [ { "$month": "$dt" }, { "$month": "$$NOW" } ] } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but month, year is not fixed.

Comment: @RiteshArora Can you pass the year from your code?